# Javascript: Write a higher-order function to use the context of the object from which it is called

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a function that adds logging to any function. Something like:

```
function loggerise(f) {
   return function() {
      const r = f(...arguments)
      console.log(r)
      return r
   }
}
```

Except that the above doesn't work.

Tested on this object:

```
const oracle = {
  question:'',
  ask: function(q) {this.question=q},
  answer: function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'},
  answerLog: loggerise(function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'})
}

oracle.ask('the universe');
alert(oracle.answer()); // correct result, no logging
alert(loggerise(()=>(42))()) // correct result and logging, not in object
alert(oracle.answerLog()); // wrong result and logging, in object
```

The function gives the result `Answer to undefined is 42` which shows that the object's context is lost. I've tried to define the context explicitly but I am getting that wrong:

```
function loggerise(f) {
   const that = this
   return function() {
      const r = f.apply(that,arguments)
      console.log(r)
      return r
   }
}
```

Is giving the same wrong result, as do some variants of the same.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boisvert/f3ab8qog/21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass over [the value of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) when calling the function, otherwise you lose the context when calling methods in objects.

You can use [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) with:

#### [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = f.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}
```

```js
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = f.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}

const oracle = {
  question:'',
  ask: function(q) {this.question=q},
  answer: function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'},
  answerLog: loggerise(function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'})
}

oracle.ask('the universe');
console.log(oracle.answer()); 
console.log(loggerise(()=>(42))());
console.log(oracle.answerLog());
```

#### [`Function#call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = f.call(this, ...arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}
```

```js
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = f.call(this, arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}

const oracle = {
  question:'',
  ask: function(q) {this.question=q},
  answer: function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'},
  answerLog: loggerise(function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'})
}

oracle.ask('the universe');
console.log(oracle.answer());
console.log(loggerise(()=>(42))());
console.log(oracle.answerLog());
```

#### [`Reflect.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply)

```
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = Reflect.apply(f, this, arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}
```

```js
function loggerise(f) {
  return function() {
    const r = Reflect.apply(f, this, arguments);
    console.log(r)
    return r;
  }
}

const oracle = {
  question:'',
  ask: function(q) {this.question=q},
  answer: function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'},
  answerLog: loggerise(function() {return 'Answer to '+this.question+' is 42'})
}

oracle.ask('the universe');
console.log(oracle.answer());
console.log(loggerise(()=>(42))());
console.log(oracle.answerLog());
```

---

There is not much difference between these. It is down to preference which one you pick.